# Checking a file whether if it exists in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a file `EN.quickdic` in the location below

[image]

If I check if file exists - > It always returns **FALSE**

```
    val dirPath: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath
    val filePath = dirPath.plus("/$Constants.DICTIONARY_FILE")
    // - > /data/user/0/com.cnx.dictionarytool/files/EN.quickdic
    val file = File(filePath)
    // Check if file does not exists
    if (file.exists()) {
           // -------------------- > This is still not true even if file is present
    }
```

**Question**: How to check if the file exists there

Comment: You simply use the wrong file path as you can see.

Comment: val dirPath: String = getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.absolutePath, I tired this and file.exist is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have runtime permissions available
- I have declared permissions in manifest

**I use the below code:**

```
fun isDictionaryExists(): Boolean {
        val isFileFound = false
        val externalStorageVolumes: Array<out File> = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null)
        for (item: File in externalStorageVolumes) {
            val primaryExternalStorage = item
            Log.d("","")
            return traverseForCheckingTheFile(item)
        }
        return isFileFound
    }

private fun traverseForCheckingTheFile(dir: File): Boolean {
    if (dir.exists()) {
        val files = dir.listFiles()
        for (i in files.indices) {
            val file = files[i]
            if (file.isDirectory) {
                Log.d("","")
                traverseForCheckingTheFile(file)
            } else {
                Log.d("","")
                if(file.endsWith(DICTIONARY_FILE)){
                    //Dictionary file found
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

---

**From the dictionary I call `isDictionaryExists()`**

Answer (score 0):

try checking that file exists like below

```
     public static boolean fileExists(File directory, String fileName)
{
    File file = new File(directory,fileName);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```